# VS2019 unable to add controller

Tags: visual-studio

Please help, I am unable to add new controller in VS2019 (latest version 16.7.2)

I got:

Method not found: 'EnvDTE.Project Microsoft.WebTools.Scaffolding.Core.FactoryConfig.IsaffolderFactoryConfigEvaluationContext.get_ActiveProject()

I already upgraded it to the latest 16.7.2 and removed .vs folder, clean solution and project .. but no luck..

Regards

Comment: I followed this guy who took the issue to Syncfusion: https://forums.asp.net/post/6321324.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I repaired VS 2019 installation and it works properly now..
still don't know why this can be happened

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, second in 3 months due to a vs update
My problem was with Syncfusion extensions

1. Disable your Syncfusion extensions
2. Close Visual Studio 2019
3. Re-open Visual Studio 2019

You may have to add a blank controller
you can then add a new controller or scaffolded item from the context menu.

Hope that this helps